# How to Make a transparency effect on a Silver light shape

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to make a transparency effect on a Silver light shape. Like we do on a PNG image. How to do? For example, if I cut a hole in a PNG image, I'm able to see throug. How to do the same on a Silver light shape?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with two shapes in Expression Blend and it is easy, you draw the two shapes and select them both then you right click > combine > Exlude Overlap and you have a new shape where the overlapping part is missing, and you can see through. :)

Or i think you could play with Opacity Masks too, but i never used them before.

Comment: Thank U, It's working. In Expression Blend draw the two shapes and select them both then right click > combine > Exlude Overlap is Working. but I need that in code behind(silver light).How to do the same on a Silver light ?

Comment: @Jegadeesh So you wanna create the shapes in code behind and combine them in code too. I think that wont work because if you combine two shapes then you get one complex shape which is represented with a path. So you would have to create the result path in code behind and not the shapes then it works.

Comment: @Jegadeesh if you wanna create it dynamically from code behind i would suggest you create it with expression blend and use the path data in your code behind to create the shape, or you create a user control and then you use this in your application.